# How to specify URL correctly for connection pool in Weblogic

Tags: jdbc, weblogic, datasource, connection-pooling

How would I create a connection pool with the below information. I think I am getting wrong in URL.

```
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myDB01.com)(PORT = 1821))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = myDB.com)
    )
  )
```

I tried specifying the below in URL, but, didn't work

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@myDB01.com:1821:myDB.com
```

This is the exception I see in the logs on server start up

```
oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

Note: I am able to connect to the DB from Oracle client successfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use this format:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:[USER/PASSWORD]@//[HOST][:PORT]/SERVICE
```

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But, I have to wait another 8 mins for accepting the answer as per the community validations :)

Answer (score 1):

Version 10.3 of Oracle weblogic has a bug in its console application. When it generates the URL for your database, it is generated with this format:

jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT:SERVICE

But the console SHOULD generate with this format:

jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT/SERVICE

Pay attention to the character between PORT and SERVICE.